# How to define insert function of tree in correct manner in C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference

In C, if I have a tree or linked list, I have to declare a function for insertion like

```
insert(Node ** node)
```

so I can insert a new root/head.
My question is, how to write it with references in C++?

Comment: How about `std::set` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would write the function as

```
ReturnType insert(Node* &node)
```

That is, the parameter is a reference to the `Node*` variable holding the root of the tree.  From there, you would proceed as usual, except that compared with the C version of the function you wouldn't need to dereference `node` to reassign the root  For example, if you were to write the following in the initial (C) version of the code:

```
*node = /* ... something ... */
```

You would just write

```
node = /* ... something ... */
```

in the updated version of the code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As templatetypedef said. Or:

```
ReturnType insert(Node &node)
```

which is what I would prefer. I like to type `.` instead of `->` (saves a char :))

Caller would of course have to ensure that he creates `Node` objects with proper scope or creates them using `new`.

```
Node notGood;
Node *goodPtr = new Node();

insert(notGood); //problem
insert(*goodPtr); //ok
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  Perhaps I'm missing something, but I honestly don't see how this function could be implemented by taking in a reference to a node.  We might be making different assumptions here, but I would assume that the parameter was a pointer to the root of the tree, which would be initially NULL and then reassigned later.

Comment: you meant ReturnType insert(Node * &node)?

Comment: @templatetypedef No. I did mean just `&` not `*&` (that you already provided and I referred).. basic change in the struct being nodes are stored by ref not by ptr.. and no in this case it won't be possible to have a NULL root (ref can't be NULL).. may be there are more such issues I haven't thought of.. !?